# Why did Thomas Paine use both "hath" and "has" in the same sentence?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, writing-style, archaicisms

My understanding is that "hath" is archaic, but has exactly the same meaning as "has".

But then why would an educated writer use both in the same sentence when writing a formal article?

Example from *Common Sense* (1776):

> "... but it **hath** so far happened that the first **has** failed, and the second **has** withdrawn her influence."

He uses both words throughout the text, often in the same sentence, causing me to think that he must perceive some distinction between the two in style or connotation, if not denotation.

Comment: It may be worth adding information that at least in the [Project Gutenberg edition](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/147/147-h/147-h.htm), *hath* appears 83 times and *has* only 11.

Comment: It's worth noting that Common Sense was a pamphlet, not a book.  This was sort of at the borderline between formal and informal communications.  You wouldn't expect someone today to adhere to all the formal rules of English in Twitter, or even Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Google Ngrams for [**hath,has**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hath%2Chas&year_start=1600&year_end=1900&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) is interesting: Unsurprisingly, as **hath** declined, **has** grew in popularity. The crossover point was c. 1693. By 1799 – the publication date – the frequency of **hath** was 0.02% and **has** was 0.17% - a ratio of approximately 1:8.

It is remarkable to see so many "haths", but nevertheless, if we look at a similar phenomenon, the periphrastic “do”, we can see that it is currently possible to say “Has he any money?”, or “Does he have any money?” and the same person might say either or both, even in the same sentence without any significance.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I did note that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Ha! You did the exact opposite! I was too bothered with the maths.

Comment: Is it possible that Paine viewed the two as alternate spellings of the same word which he always pronounced the same?  That would explain the acceptability (at a time of less standardization in spelling) of using both in one article.  But it still doesn't explain the motivation to do so.

Comment: @Citizen *Is it possible that Paine viewed the two as alternate spellings of the same word which he always pronounced the same?* No. That is not possible. It is safe to say that he was able to distinguish the difference between **has** and **hath** - as was the rest of the population of the English-speaking world.

Comment: "as was the rest of the population of the English-speaking world" -- If that's the case, then how did the one word ever evolve from the other?

Comment: @Citizen It is indeed the case. However, the evolution from hath to has is another question: you should ask it... :)

Comment: I just did.  But whatever, this site seems to be pretty meh.  Have fun.